# TextBox bound to DateTime via converter formats itself while typing

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-4.0, textbox, converters

I have a TextBox bound to a DateTime using a converter that implements Convert and ConvertBack. UpdateSourceTrigger is set to PropertyChanged so that validation is done as the user types. Here is the problem:

1. User types a character
2. Converter parses this to a DateTime
3. Property in ViewModel is updated and validated
4. Converter then converts this DateTime back into a string and changes the string in the text box

This is undesirable as the text can change to a full date while the user has only typed part of a date. How can I stop the UI from doing this? Note that this has only become a problem since upgrading from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 because of this feature:

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's the reason why the `TextBox.Text` property has a default value of `LostFocus` for the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) value. Why do you need to set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Data Validation](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html), which allows you to check if the typed value fulfills a certain condition (e.g. a regex) before the property gets the typed value -> Converter gets only called if the condition is fulfilled. 
Another suggestion would be that you check in your Converter via a regex if the typed value is a DateTime and convert it only if it matches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually upgrading a very large project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 that was originally designed by someone else and changing the validation would be a huge amount of work. I ended up making a custom control that blocks updates to the text of the text box while the user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Limit the length of the number that can be entered to 12 (This is arbitrary)
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 12 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If KeyAscii < 32 Then
        Exit Sub    ' let it go, it is a control char like backspace
    End If

    If InStr("0123456789.", Chr$(KeyAscii)) > 0 Then
        If InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".") > 0 Then
            If Chr$(KeyAscii) = "." Then
                KeyAscii = 0    ' do not allow more than one decimal point
                Beep
                MsgBox "Only 2 decimal places to be allowed", vbCritical
                Exit Sub

            ElseIf Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".") + 1)) >= 2 Then
                KeyAscii = 0    ' do not allow more than 2 digits past decimal point
                Beep
                MsgBox "Only 2 decimal places to be allowed", vbCritical
                Exit Sub

            End If
        End If
    Else
        Beep
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If

    If Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, "$") + 1)) >= 1 Or KeyAscii < 32 Then
        If Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".") + 1)) >= 2 Then

            If KeyAscii < 32 Then Beep: Exit Sub
            TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "$#,###")
        Else
            If KeyAscii < 32 Then Beep: Exit Sub
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text
        End If
    ElseIf Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, "$") + 1)) >= 0 Or KeyAscii < 32 Then
        If Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".") + 1)) >= 2 Then

            If KeyAscii < 32 Then Beep: Exit Sub
            TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "$#,###")
        Else
            If KeyAscii < 32 Then Beep: Exit Sub
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = "$" & TextBox1.Text
        End If
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    If Len(Mid$(TextBox1.Text, InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".") + 1)) >= 3 Then
        TextBox1.Value = Format(PaidCreditCardForfrm.TextBox1.Value, "$#,###")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you point out why this code solves the problem as well, not just to only provide the code, as it is difficult to learn from your code, considering that another answer already exists in the same thread (and was accepted).